# Different usage of « Qui sait », depending on a negative or positive context

Tags: expressions

J'ai rencontré de nombreuses phrases avec l'expression « Qui sait », et tout porte à croire que :

---

Est-ce que l'on emploie la construction « Qui sait si ... ne ... pas » quand tout laisse prévoir que quelque chose de désagréable se produira ?

***Dans un contexte négatif :***

> **Qui sait si** elle **ne** va **pas** le larguer du jour au lendemain ?
>
> (Plutôt que de dire carrément) : **Qui sait**, elle va **peut-être** le larguer du jour au lendemain ?

---

Quand il s'agit d'un changement favorable, en revanche, je remarque une tendance à éviter la construction négative, ainsi qu'à ne pas utiliser la conjonction « si ».

***Dans un contexte positif :***

> **Qui sait**, voir l'intérieur fera **peut-être** resurgir quelques souvenirs ?
>
> (Plutôt que de dire) : **Qui sait si** voir l'intérieur **ne** fera **pas** resurgir quelques souvenirs ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas spécialement l'impression qu'il y a forcément une connotation négative avec *qui c'est si... ne... pas* : *qui sait si demain tu ne vas pas trouver l'amour ?*.

Comment: d'accord avec @SimonDéchamps On pourrait très bien dire: qui sait si il ne va pas gagner le gros lot?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps & radouxju I see. With my initial interpretation out of the picture, now I wonder if the negative construction "***Qui sait s'il ne va pas** gagner le gros lot ?*" deals with a somewhat **lower possibility** than to say "***Qui sait, il va peut-être** gagner le gros lot ?*"  Merci.

Comment: I don't feel it this way. In both cases, you insist on the fact that it could happen, there is a chance. It's optimistic (or pessimistic if it's about something bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Qui sait si / si ne pas = expression d'un doute.**

*Qui sait si elle viendra ?* Il y a une possibilité qu'elle vienne, avec un doute.

*Qui sait si elle ne chantera pas une chanson ?* Il y a une possibilité qu'elle chante une chanson.

Globalement:

- *qui sait si + positif* : on doute si cela va arriver.
- *qui sait si + négatif* : cela peut arriver (par surprise).

**Qui sait, + affirmation** = peut-être que l'affirmation est vraie.

Answer (score 1):

J'ai écrit en gros pavé en pensant être sur la bonne piste et j'ai fini par me rendre compte que j'avais inversé les phrases qui « se disaient » et les phrases qui « ne se disaient pas » et ça ne m'a pas choqué une seconde, preuve qu'elles sont interchangeables ^^

Maintenant que je les ai lues plusieurs fois je dirais les secondes formulations dans les deux cas, donc à mon avis non, il n'y a pas de schéma particulier en fonction du contexte positif ou négatif